# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver showing null on the browser

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets, jdbc

Hi I am having some trouble while I am trying to access my database. The connection to the database is not getting established.

In the web browser I am getting the following output:

In Connection Db

In try before registering driver

null

```
Below is the code snippet I am using to establish the connection.

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ConnectionDB extends HttpServlet {


    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Data";

    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "";


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        pw.println("<h2>In Connection Db</h2>");
        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            pw.println("<h2>In try before registering driver</h2>");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            pw.println("<h2>In try</h2>");
            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            pw.println("<h2>After connection</h2>");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
```

My classpath variable is set as follows
CLASSPATH = C:\Database\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to specify the port number for the JDBC URL. For MySQL this is usually 3306. So, your JDBC URL should be:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Data
```

However, you may find that the root cause if because your mysql connector is not in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder which participates in the webapp's runtime classpath. Just copy the JAR file straight in the directory `/WEB-INF/lib` and rebuild/redeploy/restart.

In addition, I assume that you are using a Java Application Server (as you are creating Servlets). Therefore, I would consider using a JDBC Connection Pool as an alternative.